# Resize textbox everytime to fit the text length

Tags: asp.net, javascript

In my [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) page I have a text box which shows data which is bind to an (JavaScript) object variable.
I want that textbox to resize everytime, the JavaScript object, e.g. result.title will change everytime.

**Important**:
I want to fit the textbox exactly to the text length inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a great tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/07/29/build-auto-expanding-textarea-1/) that teaches you how to make a jQuery plugin to do exactly what your talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `onChange`:

```
<textarea onChange="resize(this)"></textarea>

<script>
function resize(el) {
    el.cols = el.value.length;
}
</scrip>
```

Btw are you using Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery plug-in: http://www.unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/